# How do I add a string in the input prompt

Tags: python, string, input

```
for eachemployee in Employeelist:
    name = str(input("Could you tell me what is your name:  "))
    print ("Hello!"+name)
    income = int(input("May I ask your monthly income:  "))
```

I want to make the input prompt say people's name while asking income, for example:

If I type `hui` when `"Could you tell me what is your name:  "`, I want the next question to ask `"May I ask hui's monthly income:  "`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Actually, it would probably be better to do this instead:

```
income = int(input("May I ask {}{} monthly income:  "
                   .format(name, "'" if name.endswith('s') else "'s")))
```

By using a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) and [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith), we ensure that we do not accidentally add a `'s` on the end of a name that already ends in `s`.

---

You can just insert the name into the prompt string with [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
income = int(input("May I ask {}'s monthly income:  ".format(name)))
```

Also, there is no reason to do `str(input(...))` since `input` always returns a string object.

Finally, you should use a `,` with `print` instead of `+`:

```
print("Hello!", name)
```

Otherwise, the output will be `Hello!hui`, which isn't very readable.

Comment: Good point.  I've edited my answer to handle this case.  I think names ending in `s` is the only time you need to do this (although I sometimes do it for names ending in `z` such as `iCodez'` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for eachemployee in Employeelist:
    name = input("Could you tell me what is your name:  ") # str unnecessary 
    print ("Hello! " + name)
    income = int(input("May I ask {0}'s monthly income:".format(name)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way:

```
income = int(input("May I ask " + name + "'s your monthly income:  "))
```